# animate speedometer needle with pure css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have tried my best here [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/). Now I want to animate the center needle point slowly to fastly from left to right. I have heard about css  keyframes and tried it. But, it goes left and right. I didn't get the expected result. How do I animate this needle using just pure css?

**CSS**

```
#logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid #000;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
#logo .needle
{
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
    <span class="speedometer"></span>
    <span class="needle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/2/

use `@keyframes`

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```css
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-right: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#logo .needle {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999999;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: move 5s infinite;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
  <span class="needle"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

design a dashboard gauge  for speedmeter.

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/20/)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I could almost do it the needle moves like you want but moves away from the center http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/1/

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes move{
0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}
10%{transform:rotate(-45deg);}
20%{transform:rotate(30deg);}
50%{transform:rotate(80deg);}
100%{transform:rotate(90deg);}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Akshay's just needs `transform-origin: bottom;` after line 28 in the CSS.