# How to create this gauge without javascript

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this gauge, with no luck. The only solution I've found so far involves js. My goal is to achieve this without any javascript, just using css3 and html.

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I think you could reasonably approximate that shape with a number of rectangles properly rotated but, why would you do that? Is that an exercise?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia is a requirement for a website I'm building

Comment: Why can't you use a background image or an svg? Why do you want to create that with html elements?

Comment: care to comment, downvoter?

Comment: @it_Concepto are you looking for gate that moves all the time or just when page loads?

Comment: I downvoted because it's not clear what you want to achieve (Is the gauge static or does it need to move? How are you going to use it?) and I couldn't see much effort in your question (What have you tried so far?)

Comment: @GRC yes, the gate needs to move dynamically based on a value.

Comment: @it_Concepto where are you getting values from and do they change while you are viewing page?

Answer (score 1):

This has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814639/animate-speedometer-needle-with-pure-css) using CSS3 keyframes.

[Here's the example](http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"> <span class="speedometer"></span>
    <span class="needle"></span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#logo .speedometer {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid #000;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
#logo .needle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-animation:move 5s infinite;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin:bottom;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```