# Radio Button - Image + text selector using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create radio buttons with colors(instead of buttons). Clicking on a particular colour will display the colour name along with the corresponding image of that colour for the car. The screen would look like this
[image: cars]

In the ratings section both the progress bar and overall rating meter must have animation.
How should I align according to the requirement(unfortunatly not allowed to use bootstrap), this is what I have done so far -

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.red .button span {
  background:red;
}

.silver .button span {
  background: silver;
}

.grey .button span {
  background: grey;
}

.blue .button span {
  background: blue;
}

.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}

.grey input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: url("images/grey.jpg")
}

.red input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: url("images/red.jpg")
}

.silver input:checked ~ .layer {
  background:  url("images/silver.jpg")
}

.blue input:checked ~ .layer {
  background:  url("images/blue.jpg")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="code.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  

  <label class="silver">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="silver">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="button">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label class="grey">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="grey">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="button">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label class="red">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="button">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label class="blue">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="button">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </label>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not enough details i mean what do you want to do

Comment: I've created the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2puhr7m9/) for your question to understand your issue or problem, but I didn't get the point what you are asking for? Can you please explain more...

Comment: Need to align the image on clicking the radio button and animation of meter

Comment: I have added the process bar also, check the pen while I copy the code here.

Comment: @SaifUrRahman not able to see the link , could you attach again

Comment: Check out the Answer section below

Comment: @Akhilesh The link is on the last line, check the Answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little javascript code to show different images according to the buttons:

```js
function display() {

    var images = {
        silver: {
            img: "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/car-images/large/Ford/Ford-Mustang/3835/ford-mustang-ingot-silver_7e7e7e.jpg",
            description: "Car 1",
            speed: 50
        },
        grey: {
            img: "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/car-images/large/Ford/Ford-Mustang/3835/ford-mustang-magnetic_3e3e3e.jpg",
            description: "Car 2",
            speed: 80

        },
        red: {
            img: "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/car-images/large/Ford/Ford-Mustang/3835/ford-mustang-race-red_c61008.jpg",
            description: "Car 3",
            speed: 70
        },

        blue: {
            img: "https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/car-images/large/Ford/Ford-Mustang/3835/ford-mustang-absolute-black_1a1a1a.jpg",
            description: "Car 4",
            speed: 90
        }

    };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (document.colorpicker.color[i].checked == true) {
            var checkNumber = document.colorpicker.color[i];
            console.log(document.stage.src);
            document.stage.src = images[checkNumber.value].img;
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = images[checkNumber.value].description;
            move(images[checkNumber.value].speed);
        }
    }
}

function move(wd) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("progress");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= wd) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            elem.innerHTML = "Speed: " + width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap the radio button within a `<form id="colorpicker> ... </form>`.

Add the attribute `onClick="display(this.form)"` to every `<input>`

Add a placeholder image before the form `<img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/car-images/large/Ford/Ford-Mustang/3835/ford-mustang-yellow-tricoat_eda600.jpg" name="stage" />`

Add this to the html for the progress bar:

```
<div id="bar">
<div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for the bar :

```
#bar {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: black;
  margin:auto;

}

#progress {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fcec03;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML for description box:
`<p id="description">Placeholder Image</p>`

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/saifsmailbox98/pen/JZZgaM [updated]

Comment: Added progress bar

Comment: You can change the description to the required color name.

Comment: You can load the first car data on load instead of the placeholder car data.

Comment: Here's some demo on the speedometer overall rating progressbar:
http://jsfiddle.net/99oakz7w/2/ found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814639/animate-speedometer-needle-with-pure-css