# How design a speedometer with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a speedometer as shown in the image:[image]

I'm having a hard time making that design with CSS. So I need help from a CSS master. How can I place the numbers like that, just like the blue bars.

So far what I tried grab this:

```css
#speedometer .wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-top-left-radius: 360px;
      border-top-right-radius: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .indicator-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top-left-radius: 360px;
    border-top-right-radius: 360px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 400;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .bar-1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    transform: rotate(-140deg);
    /* background-color: rgb(114, 114, 238); */
    background-color: green;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .bar-2 {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* background-color: rgb(69, 69, 204); */
    background-color: yellow;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .bar-3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
    /* background-color: rgb(40, 40, 180); */
    background-color: purple;
}

#speedometer .wrapper .bar-4 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    /* background-color: rgb(15, 15, 167); */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="speedometer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="indicator-wrapper">
            <div class="indicator-wrapper-inner">
                <div id="indicator"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bar bar-1"></div>
        <div class="bar bar-2"></div>
        <div class="bar bar-3"></div>
        <div class="bar bar-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a lot of help to position the numbers like that, add the states: 'Good', 'Average', 'Bad', 'Very Bad' at the top. Likewise, add spacing between the bars. I know I'm asking a lot but the truth is costing me a lot. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I would highly recommend SVG here

Comment: I don't have much experience in SVG. Could you recommend a course?

Comment: This link may be help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814639/animate-speedometer-needle-with-pure-css

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just HTML and CSS you can put each number at the top of a long thin element which is then rotated about the bottom center of the speedometer.

There are 11 numbers so the number of degrees between each rotated element is 180/10;

Then each number is rotated back so it doesn't look rotated.

This snippet sets a CSS variable --num to the total number of numbers and uses CSS calc to calculate the rotations needed.

```css
.speedometer {
  --num: 11;
  /* the total number of numbers */
  width: 100vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.speedometer>* {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 1em);
  width: 2em;
  height: 70%;
  --deg: calc(180deg / calc(var(--num) - 1));
  transform: rotate(calc(-90deg + calc((var(--n) - 1) * var(--deg))));
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.speedometer>* * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.speedometer>*>* {
  transform: rotate(calc(90deg - ((var(--n) - 1) * var(--deg))));
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(6) {
  --n: 6;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(7) {
  --n: 7;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(8) {
  --n: 8;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(9) {
  --n: 9;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(10) {
  --n: 10;
}

.speedometer> :nth-child(11) {
  display: inline-block;
  --n: 11;
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer">
  <div>
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>20</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>30</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>40</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>50</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>60</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>70</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>80</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>90</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[gauge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYeI2.png)

Here is one more design you may like

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #15222e, #8100E0);
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(21, 34, 46, 0.25);
  padding: 35px 40px 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32), 0 1px 9px -1px #15222e;
}

.wrapper-header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
  margin: 30px 0 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.heart {
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: simplePulse ease-in-out 1.1s infinite;
}

.gauge {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09), 0 0 35px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.29);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* safari fix */
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
.gauge.min-scaled {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.gauge-center {
  content: '';
  color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: #15222E;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 -13px 15px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  right: 21%;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.gauge-center .label, .gauge-center .number {display:block; width: 100%; text-align: center; border:0!important;}
.gauge-center .label {font-size:0.75em; opacity:0.6; margin:1.1em 0 0.3em 0;}
.gauge-center .number {font-size:1.2em;}

.needle {
  width: 78px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #15222E;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 20px;
  transform-origin: 100% 4px;
  animation: speed 5s infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
  transform: rotate(70deg); // set degree of the needle 
}

.slice-colors .st {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 80px solid #000;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
}
.slice-colors .st.slice-item:nth-child(1) {
  border-bottom-color: #EB8916;
  left: -5px;
}
.slice-colors .st.slice-item:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom-color: #15C63C;
  transform: rotate(145deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  top: 12px;
  left: -30px;
}
.slice-colors .st.slice-item:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom-color: #15C63C;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  top: -50px;
  left: 25px;
}
.slice-colors .st.slice-item:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom-color: #D74141;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -28px;
}
.slice-colors .st.slice-item:nth-child(5) {
  border-bottom-color: #D74141;
  transform: rotate(28deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wrapper-header">CSS Gauge</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gauge">
    <div class="slice-colors">
      <div class="st slice-item"></div>
      <div class="st slice-item"></div>
      <div class="st slice-item"></div>
      <div class="st slice-item"></div>
      <div class="st slice-item"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="needle"></div>
    <div class="gauge-center">
      <div class="label">RISK</div>
      <div class="number">HIGH</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```